# How can I connect a path to an object in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, svg

I created a sankey diagram (using the awesome [sankeymatic.com](http://sankeymatic.com/build/)), which I then saved as an .svg and opened in Inkscape.

The resulting diagram has nodes represented as objects and flow represented as paths.  The path stroke width represents the flow quantity (in this case dollars), and each object is the same width as the total of the connected flows widths.

[image]

What I'd like to do is connect the paths to their corresponding objects so that I can move the object and have the associated path endpoints move together.  Is that possible? And, if so, how can I do it?

I've tried adding nodes to the object, but can't get them to properly lineup with the path endpoints, or to connect them to move together.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to connect a path to a filled object like that.  You can't connect an open path to a closed path in vector image editing software. It's not possible.

Inkscape does have a Diagram Connectors tool, but it won't work for this, because you need to connect the objects using the Diagram Connectors tool itself - which is fairly rudimentary in functionality. Connectors are straight lines only, and although you can bend a connector path after you've made one, when you move the objects the path will be redrawn as a straight line.

It is possible to have nodes overlap using snapping to get them exact, and you could move the object and an open path together by selecting the nodes with the Edit by Nodes tool, so that they move together. This is not a physical connection that can be made permanent.

Example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I've discovered is to

1. Convert the object to path: *Path → Object to Path*.
2. Select all paths, including the former object.
3. Use a lasso to select all the desired nodes (i.e. all the former object and the end points of the paths).
4. Use the arrow keys to reposition the nodes.

Comment: Conversion to path is not needed, if the objects are paths already (which they probably are in the example above). Step 2 should be performed with the selection tool or the node tool, while step 3 must be performed with the node tool.